# Most efficient way to back up computer and remove old directories?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, script

I have around 10TB of data spread across several hard drives that I occasionally back up to a singular large hard drive. I need these backups to happen more often than "occasionally," so I am writing a script to back up all the drives every night. Because it takes longer than 8 hours to copy 10TB of data to this drive, I only overwrite files on the backup drive that have been modified since the previous backup. This makes the backups happen much faster since the majority of those 10TB don't change.

However, sometimes I rename folders or move files around on the source drives. When this happens, my script has no way to know that they aren't new files and then copies them over to the backup drive again. This is OK, but now my "backup" has two versions of the same file/folder. As time goes on, these old files/folders continue to pile up and pollute the backup, which is NOT ideal.

I suppose I can have my script iterate over all the directories in the backup and remove any files/folders it finds that don't exist on the source drives. But is this really the most efficient/best way to do this? Do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Use Sync Back Pro (2brightsparks.com). I use this and have used it for over a decade. It backs up (mirrors) and syncs (copies just differences). Can be scheduled and still run on demand.

Comment: `robocopy` has a `/mir` option.